# Core Data model extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have established the following model showing relationships.

[image]

Custom UITableViewCell subclasses update the Story selected property when they are actually selected.

This is working absolutely fine although I have now been asked to offer some form of persistence of the selected Story objects.

How can I build this SavedSelection object to fit into the model below?

Comment: are you asking how to introduce new tables?

Comment: Please clarify if you're trying to simply save the selection state between user sessions or if you're trying to allow the user to save multiple sets of selected stories. If the former, it should just be a matter of checking the selected field when the view is loaded and setting the selection appropriately. If the latter, you should just need to create a new SavedSelection entity with a to-many relationship to Story. The SavedSelection entity would then be created/updated by whatever user mechanism you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only novel thing is you have a many-to-many relation, where `SavedSelection` has many Stories, and a Story may belong to many `SavedSelection`s.  CoreData can do this without anything special or any kind of explicit join table.

You just create a `SavedSelection` entity, make it have a to-many `selectedStories` property that leads off to the `Story` entity.  In return you make a `savedSelections` property that's to-many and leads off to `SavedSelections`.  There's no step three.

Comment: Thanks very much. I come from a database background and I find this abstraction layer quite confusing at times. Once you have explained it with the above I was able to look at the SQL store and tweak my code accordingly. Thank you very much

Comment: When I was typing this out the first time I was trying to do it the hard way too ... conceptually you could have a SavedSelection(has many) ->> SavedSelectionMember(has one) -> Story, which would do about the same thing.